# Uploading photo to firebase storage not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to firebase storage when users click a certain button within my chat app, but it's not working.

**Here is the code for uploading**

```
if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                 public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                     // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                     Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                     // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                     FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, downloadUrl.toString());
                     mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                 }
            });
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Are there any errors? Could it be an authentication issue?

Comment: check firebase storage rules in your app console, if you are not using any firebase authentication method then your rules must allow read and write to all users ( not just authenticated users ) to be able to upload or download any file.

Comment: I got no error messages at all, it just dosen't upload anything to the database.
i don't think it's an authentication issue normal text messages works fine and it got the same rules as images
"service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}"

Comment: @tokaaliamien does it upload to storage?

Comment: @PeterHaddad No

Answer (score 2):

```
public void uploadFile(Uri filePath, UploadImageInterface uploadImageInterface) {
StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_STORAGE_PATH).child("images");
if (filePath != null) {
    StorageReference filepathRef = mStorageRef.child("pic" + CommonUtilities.getTimeStampLong() + ".JPG");
    filepathRef.putFile(filePath)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String imageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() + "";
                uploadImageInterface.onSuccess(imageUrl);
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                uploadImageInterface.onFailure(exception.getMessage())       
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add Rules and also need to check your storage path

Comment: Add Roules as:-    
    service firebase.storage {
    match /b/projectname-dfd60.appspot.com/o {
      match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
     }
    }

Comment: Above configuration worked for me . Please specify error you get.